# OGR - Error trying to intersect two layers

Tags: python, point, buffer, ogr, intersect

I'm trying to intersect a buffer with a point shapefile using **OGR**, but when I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\xxx\eclipse-workspace\xxx\Final.py", line 40, in <module>

buff_lyr.Intersection (shp2, result_lyr)

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 2263, in Intersection

return _ogr.Layer_Intersection(self, *args, **kwargs)

 TypeError: in method 'Layer_Intersection', argument 2 of type 'OGRLayerShadow *'
```

Here is my script:

```
import ogr

import os

import sys

path = 'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/xxx/xxx/archivos'

os.chdir(path)

driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(driverName)

shp = 'avereproj.shp'

dataSource = driver.Open(shp, 0)

shp2 = 'Cober_point3.shp' 

dataSource2 = driver.Open(shp2, 0)

numLayers = dataSource.GetLayerCount() 

print 'Numero de capas: ', numLayers 

layer = dataSource.GetLayer(0) 

numFeatures = layer.GetFeatureCount() 

print 'Numero de registros: ',numFeatures

spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()

print spatialRef

memory_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName ('memory')

memory_ds = memory_driver.CreateDataSource ('temp')

buff_lyr = memory_ds.CreateLayer ('buffer')

buff_feat = ogr.Feature (buff_lyr.GetLayerDefn())

for ave_feat in layer:

    buff_geom = ave_feat.geometry().Buffer(100)

    tmp = buff_feat.SetGeometry(buff_geom)

    tmp = buff_lyr.CreateFeature (buff_feat)

result_lyr = memory_ds.CreateLayer('result')

buff_lyr.Intersection (shp2, result_lyr)

print ('Polygons: []'.format(result_lyr.GetFeatureCount()))
```

I have been trying to figure out how to fix this for a while but I can't find the problem.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OGRGeometry::Intersection method takes a **geometry** object as input, but you're passing it a string.

You passed shp2 to dataSource2, but you're not using it anywhere in your code. Extract the layer from it, then the desired feature from that, and finally the feature's geometry, and pass *that* to Intersection. Also, Intersection takes only one arguement, assign the result to a variable outside it:

```
result_lyr = buff_lyr.Intersection(geom2)
```

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of that error. I extracted the geometry following these steps:    
    - shp2 = 'Cober_point2.shp' 
 
    - dataSource2 = driver.Open(shp2, 0)

  -  lyr2 = dataSource2.GetLayer(0)

  -  feature2 = lyr2.GetFeature(0)

  -  geometry2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()

But I get - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeometryRef'.

I have read that that could be because the geometry was empty, but when I import it to arcGIS, there are points in it. So I don't know what could be wrong now. I will keep searching. Thank you for your quick answers.

Comment: Is your Layer being imported correctly? When you do lyr2.GetFeatureCount(), how many features it returns? Is the feature 0 really the one you want? It may be that your data has geom-less features that you are unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

The [`intersection`](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#a5202606175f7e7dcd76c3eb237ac8303) method is expecting a layer but you are giving a string containing the Shapefile name.

You can try `buff_lyr.Intersection (dataSource2.GetLayer(0) , result_lyr)`

Comment: Close, but not quite right. Intersection does not take a Layer object, but a Geometry one. And it only takes one input argument.

Comment: @RobertoRibeiro ... though the solution I have provided do work.

Comment: Roberto and JGH are talking about two different functions called "Intersection". Respectively: 

Intersection(Geometry self, Geometry other) -> Geometry

__________and__________ 

Intersection(Layer self, Layer method_layer, Layer result_layer, char ** options=None, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> OGRErr